# Change color scheme in tccv

Tags: color, packages, two-column, document-classes, cv

I am working with the document class `tccv`. How can I change the default color scheme? I tried it with `\usepackage{colorx}` and then the `\definecolor` command:

```
\definecolor{foregound}{HTML}{303030}
\definecolor{url}{HTML}{506060}
\definecolor{link}{HTML}{506060}
\definecolor{header}{rgb}{0.67, 0.6, 0.66}
\definecolor{personal}{rgb}{0.71, 0.45, 0.51}
```

My problem is that either there are no changes at all or it says error when I add the `\definecolor` command additionally below the sections. I would be very grateful for any kind of advice.

Comment: Welcome to tex.se! `\definecolor` gives a name to the colour being defined, but does not apply the colour to anything. What things do you want to change the colour of? e.g., to change the text colour (=foreground colour) to red, use the command `\color{red}`.

Comment: tccv class sets foreground(text) colour to grey with `\color[HTML]{303030}`, sets a font colour `\setkomafont{disposition}{\color[HTML]{801010}}`, defines a colour called 'link' with `\definecolor{link}{HTML}{506060}` and makes the urls and hyperlinks that colour with `\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=link,linkcolor=link}`, hard-codes a background colour with `\colorbox[HTML]{F5DD9D}` when defining the `tabular` holding the personal data, and so on...

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It was really helpful for me.